# How to add Mini Panel

Tags: 7, panels

I can´t mini panel in panel page because this not showing in content of panels.

I have mini panel module enable but... How can I enable mini panels in content panels??
[image]

Comment: try looking in `Custom blocks`.

Comment: Thank you, but no....is not working

Comment: are you using Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: I would suggest that this is for Drupal 7 (7.x branch of Panopoly). Mini Panels are not available for 8, at the time of writing my comment, nor at the date of the OP's question. However, the original goal of the OP might be achievable using [bootstrap_layout](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_layouts) and following some guides here: [Meta: Port Mini Panels to D8](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels/issues/2682445)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
Already solved the issue.

You have selected a layout Panopoly, I changed it to one of the "Extra laytous panels" and matter settled.